# Where is documentation on escaping/parsing of AddEnvironmentVariables on Linux targets in Azure?

Tags: linux, azure, terraform, serilog, appsettings

I'm trying to translate the following from `appsettings.json`...

```js
{
  "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication": "Verbose", // << this line
        // etc.
```

...into the `app_settings` section under a `resource "azurerm_linux_web_app" "app"` inside a Terraform script, like so:

```
app_settings = {
  myprefix_Serilog__MinimumLevel__Override__AspNetCore_Authentication = "Verbose"
```

The `AspNetCore_Authentication` part doesn't seem to work, and at this point I'm unsure if that's some *other* problem, or if I should escape the `.` from the AppSettings json key differently. The main problem is that I can't find documentation on how the escaping works in this situation.

The [Terraform documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/linux_web_app#app_settings) isn't very extensive and points to a not very useful MSDN page. [The better MSDN page on AddEnvironmentVariables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/configuration-providers#environment-variable-configuration-provider) however also does not provide any clarity on periods in keys.

My actual question for Stack Overflow: where is the documentation for how Environment Variable parsing and escaping works on Linux targets in Azure?

Comment: Are there any errors? Have you tried maybe `"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication" = "Verbose"`?

Comment: All fair questions and I will try that! But at this time I don't immediately want to fix this one issue, but I want to find the right documentation and know _how_ it works.

Comment: Yeah, I hear you. :)